# Trying to Export Each Record in an Access Table as a Separate CSV File

Tags: ms-access, vba

I put together some code that seems like ti should be working, to export each unique record in a table as a separate CSV file, but it is actually exporting ALL records as a CSV file.  This must be close, but something is off, and I can't tell what it is.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim dbThis As Database
Dim rsThis As Recordset
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef

Set dbThis = CurrentDb()

Set rsThis = dbThis.OpenRecordset("Select Distinct OrderID as dValue from Orders where OrderID is not null", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rsThis.EOF
    Debug.Print rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value
    Set qdfNew = New QueryDef
    qdfNew.SQL = "select * from Orders where OrderID = '" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & "'"
    qdfNew.Name = "qryTemp"
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Append qdfNew
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Orders", "C:\Test\" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ".csv", True
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Delete "qryTemp"
    rsThis.MoveNext
Loop
rsThis.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You're writing the query definition (`qryTemp`) but exporting `Orders` every time thru the loop.

Comment: I updated the code and now I'm getting this: 'Error 31532: Microsoft Access was unable to export the data.'  Using: DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryTemp", "C:\Test\" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ".csv", True

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error.  So shotgunning ... when you hit that error and go into break mode ... Does `qryTemp` open without error in the query designer and return data?  Does the file `"C:\Test\" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ".csv"` already exist?  Can you write any file to `"C:\Test\"`?

Comment: Just out of curisity here, why are you exporting "Orders" after going through all the effort to create that `qdfNew` QueryDef?

Comment: @ HansUp: no, I can't write any file.  That's the problem.  @ Jiggles32 19: I just thought that's how you do it.  You definitely need to pass in some parameters to the 'DoCmd.TransferText'.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I see what the problem is.  I had quotes around a numeric field.  Yes quotes are needed for text, but not for numbers.  Here is the working solution if you are filtering on a numeric field.

```
Set dbThis = CurrentDb()

Set rsThis = dbThis.OpenRecordset("Select Distinct OrderID as dValue from Orders where OrderID is not null", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rsThis.EOF
    Debug.Print rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value
    Set qdfNew = New QueryDef
    qdfNew.SQL = "select * from Orders where OrderID = " & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ""
    qdfNew.Name = "qryTemp"
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Delete "qryTemp"
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Append qdfNew
    qryTemp = qdfNew.SQL
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryTemp", "C:\Test\" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ".csv", True
    rsThis.MoveNext
Loop
rsThis.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `qryTemp = qdfNew.SQL` is unnecessary and makes your code a lot more confusing than it should be.